# fetch data in select react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

There is a form with selects, in the first one a film from a series of Star Wars is selected. And the other two should display spaceships from the selected movie. I don't really understand how to write the condition correctly, if you do it on if, then a lot of code turns out, I'm sure there is a more rational way.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Component code:

```js
class StarshipsCompare extends Component {
  swapiService = new SwapiService();
  state = {
    filmList: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.swapiService.getAllFilms().then((filmList) => {
      this.setState({ filmList });
    });
  }
  renderItems(arr) {
    return arr.map(({ id, title }) => {
      return (
        <option value={title} key={id}>
          {title}
        </option>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { filmList } = this.state;
    const items = this.renderItems(filmList);
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <p>Выберите фильм корабли из которого хотите сравнить:</p>
          <select className="custom-select">{items}</select>
          <div className="row p-5">
            <div className="col">
              <p>Выберите корабль для сравнения:</p>
              <select className="custom-select"></select>
            </div>
            <div className="col">
              <p>Выберите корабль для сравнения:</p>
              <select className="custom-select"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And fetch data:

```js
export default class SwapiService {
  _apiBase = "https://swapi.dev/api";
  async getResource(url) {
    const res = await fetch(`${this._apiBase}${url}`);

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${url}, status: ${res.status}`);
    }

    return await res.json();
  }

  getAllFilms = async () => {
    const res = await this.getResource("/films/");
    return res.results.map(this._transformFilms);
  };
}
```

Comment: what does `this._transformFilms` do?

Comment: use `onChange` to get the value of `selected` option from the main list and based on that value filter your `arr`. [React Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Comment: _transformFilms = (film) => {
    return {
      id: film.episode_id,     
      title: film.title
    };
  };

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of how I would do it. The usage of the `&&` is an elegant replacement for `if` statements in `JSX`.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="app_root"></div>    
<script type="text/babel">
// Constants representing API Data.
const MAIN_SELECT_OPTIONS = ["A", "B", "C"];
const SUB_SELECT_OPTIONS = {
  A: ["A1", "A2", "A3"],
  B: ["B1", "B2", "B3"],
  C: ["C1", "C2", "C3"]
};

const SelectState = () => {
  const [mainSelect, setMainSelect] = React.useState("");
  const [subSelect, setSubSelect] = React.useState("");

  const [subSelectOptions, setSubSelectOptions] = React.useState([]);

  const onMainSelectChange = (event) => {
    setMainSelect(event.target.value);
    setSubSelect("");

    if (event.target.value) {
      setSubSelectOptions(SUB_SELECT_OPTIONS[event.target.value]);
    } else {
      setSubSelectOptions([]);
    }
  };

  const onSubSelectChange = (event) => {
    setSubSelect(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> Main Select </h1>
      <select onChange={onMainSelectChange} value={mainSelect}>
        <option value="">Select Main</option>
        {MAIN_SELECT_OPTIONS.map((option) => (
          <option key={option} value={option}>
            {option}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <h1> Sub Select </h1>
      <select onChange={onSubSelectChange} value={subSelect}>
        {!subSelect && <option>Select a State</option>}
        {subSelectOptions.map((option) => (
          <option key={option} value={option}>
            {option}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<SelectState />, document.getElementById("app_root"));

</script>
```